# Drush Error: environment settings not found or configured for Drush command

Tags: drush

I'm working on a legacy project and am trying to see if Drush can be set up properly. I installed the `drush` executable locally, I'm not sure if that is the issue. But when I go to run a basic command like `drush cr` I get this error about "environment settings."

```
$ /home/ubuntu/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush cr
environment settings not found or configured for Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

Where are these "environment settings" supposed to be located? Googling around, I can't seem to find anything concrete. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

By the way, the executable itself seems okay:

```
$ /home/ubuntu/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush --version
 Drush Version   :  8.2.3
```

Comment: Try with the debug flags (`.../drush cr -vvv`), that should give more info

Comment: What version of Drupal? You installed Drush globally? This install method is not supported anymore. Also see the compatibility chart https://www.drush.org/latest/install/#drupal-compatibility

Comment: @leymannx Drupal version 8.5.14 I think. It's a legacy project, so I don't have much leeway to upgrade.

Comment: Is the problem resolved? Since you have Drupal 8.4+, you should use Drush 9 - ref chart leymannx linked to.